# How to get Lion a working auto_home client with NIS and NFS Server

Tags: macos, nfs

I have a working NIS/NFS server environment here, with multiple servers. One is the NIS server, that works just fine with Lion. But I can't figure out how to get the auto home mounting working.

Do you guys have any hints, make this working?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an automount record for your Directory, and you'll need home folder location records for your users or groups. I think you'll need to modify your LDAP schema so that these two types of entries are named the way a Mac expects. Not my area of expertise unfortunately.